# tinyMCE separate locations opened for images and files

Tags: javascript, browser, tinymce

I am using tinyMCE and wondering if it is possible to have the insert image button open in a different location than the insert link button. Right now both open the same directory but I would like to have each open in their own unique directory.

Is this possible or does anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: 'insert image' does reffer to which tinymce functionality/ which plugin?